# Jenkins Content Security For Custom Html Report

Tags: jenkins, content-security-policy

I have a HTML page(index.html) along with couple of js(jquery.min.js,bootstrap.min.js) and css files (copied on the server) which are published using Jenkins HTML Publisher plugin for each build of jenkins job.
In order to allow scripts and css to work I had unset the header in content policy to
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "").
I would like to know what is a better way in terms of setting the custom header as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A more nuanced, tailored [Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) should be considered to set an appropriately secure [Content Security Policy](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/) that satisfies risk versus capability. YMMV